# infinity norm of a set?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Given some closed domain $V\in\mathbb{R}^2$, is there a succinct way to describe the
maximum extent along the $x$- or $y-$ direction of any point $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)\in V$?  I'm trying to find what would be, in some sense, a max-norm of a set, but restricted to one coordinate direction.

Comment: $\sup_{x\in V} \lvert\langle x, e_1\rangle\rvert$?

Comment: of course, thanks